# Optimize calculation of white pixels in a binary image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, optimization, raspberry-pi2

I have a program which does the following steps (using OpenCV):

1. Connect to a camera
2. Start a loop
3. Fetch frame
4. Extract red channel
5. Threshold the extracted channel
6. Put it into a deque to build a buffer (right now, a three image buffer)
7. Calculate the variation among frames in the buffer (some morphology included)
8. Take that variation as a binary image
9. Count the amount of variation (white pixels)
10. If there's variation, calculate its center.

My problem is that the loop that starts with the second step, is ideally repeated 90 times a second, and the CPU it is running on is quite weak (Raspberry PI), and so I decided to benchmark the application once it bottle necked.

I broke things up into four groups. Steps 3, 4-6, 7-8 and 9. Here are some results in microseconds (benchmarks based on the system time, not CPU time, they are not 100% precise)

> Read camera:5101; Update buffer:15032; Calculate the variation:8149; Count non-zero:51665
>
> Read camera:5446; Update buffer:16335; Calculate the variation:8365; Count non-zero:50005
>
> Read camera:5394; Update buffer:15423; Calculate the variation:7163; Count non-zero:43006
>
> Read camera:7527; Update buffer:20051; Calculate the variation:7919; Count non-zero:54895
>
> Read camera:5492; Update buffer:16657; Calculate the variation:7757; Count non-zero:1034739

So it takes 5 to 7.5ms read a frame, 15 to 20ms to apply some processing and update a buffer, 7 to 8.5ms to calculate the buffer variation, and then 45ms to a second to count the amount of variation.

It spikes quite often in the last step, so that 1 second is not uncommon.

Why is it taking so much in the last step? It is a single line of code:

> variatedPixels = countNonZero(variation);

With a best case scenario of 72ms, (27ms for the first steps + 45mn for the last) I'm nowhere close to being able to process 90 frames a second, and these are timings on an overclocked RPi2. That's definitely way too optimistic for the PI.

The worst I can take are 30 FPS for the application to work, but in that case it can't drop a single frame. That means having code executing in less than 33ms.

Is there any way to reproduce that line in less than 6ms? It doesn't really seem to do that much comparing to the remaining code, something just doesn't feels right. And why does it sometimes peaks? Can it be due to a thread change?

The ideas I have so far are:

- To make the program multi-threaded. (It doesn't really need to answer
  in real-time, just can't drop frames. There's a 400ms window to
  display the results)
- Reduce the bit depth from 8bits to 3 bits after
  thresholding (it can lead to wrong results and no performance
  benefit).

Since I'm new to C++ I would like to avoid complex solutions such as multi-threading.

**EDIT:**
Here is my code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/90570c37f175fd2461b4
That's already cleaned out to be straight to the problem.
I'm probably messing up with the pointers, but it works. Please tell me in case something there is obviously wrong since I'm new, and hope the code not to be that awful. :)

**EDIT 2:**
I fixed a little bug with the measurement while cleaning up the code. Step 10 was always being executed, also it was being included by mistake under the step 9 times.
It also seems that having 5-6 "imshows" being updated at every second takes a lot of CPU on the PI. (I neglected that since in the desktop it wasn't even taking 1% CPU to display the frames to debug).

Right now I think I'm at 25-35ms. Need a a little more optimization to ensure it always works. So far the detection rate of my algorithm seems to be close to ~80%.

Comment: Can you get a lower-resolution image from the camera?

Comment: It's possible that there's an error in your measurement code and the time really isn't all in the counting. You should share more code.

Comment: @Buddy Im already at the lowest possible. VGA. If I lower it anymore it crops.

Comment: @MarkRansom Working on it. I'll not share the whole code (not that I have anything to hide, I'll eventually make it opensource once finished), but is way too big for a question like this. I'll strip everything that isn't strictly essential, and then update the question.
I didn't put it there in the first place because I hoped there was some straight simple answer telling me to do that line some other way.

Comment: Done. There is code now :)

Comment: Implement `countNonZero` yourself, see if how long it takes, go from there.

Comment: @KubaOber I don't really think that my almost zero C++ experience is enough to implement that in a more efficient way than the original developers.
The question is more of "is there an easier path for what is required?".
The code I showed isn't that big. If anyone can detect anything that's hogging more resources than the strictly required, and that is enough to reduce execution time by 10-20%, that's an answer, even if I'll have to change the question to make the answer in-topic.
Finding that bug(in the edit) made me see that it's not necessarily a countNonZero problem, and its more spread.